# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x})}}$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to figure out how to prove this. I was thinking that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find $x$ values smaller than $\epsilon$ such that some such $x$ values lead to function values >$1$, and vice versa for function values <$1$.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, or how to continue proving it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Limit of $1/x^{1/3}$ will be undefined. So undefined multiplied by anything will be undefined

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal : How about multiply by $x^{1/3}$?

Comment: What good will it do?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19: You method is fine.

Comment: And also what is $\sin(undefined)$?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19: You method is fine (if you can also find $x$ so that the value is $<-1$ (or $<0$, just to avoid that the limit might be $1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about taking the limit through two different sequences converging to zero and getting *different* answers?:

$$\begin{align}&x_n:=\frac1{2n\pi}\;,\;n\in\Bbb N\implies \frac1{\sqrt[3]{x_n}}\sin\frac1{x_n}=\sqrt[3]{2n\pi}\,\sin2n\pi=0\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\\{}\\& y_n:=\frac2{(4n+1)\pi},\;n\in\Bbb N\implies\frac1{\sqrt[3]{y_n}}\sin\frac1{y_n}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2}\,\sin\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2=\\{}\\&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\end{align}$$

and thus the limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x})}} = \infty
\quad\text{ and }\quad
 \varliminf\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sin({\frac{1}{x})}} = -\infty.
$$
 This implies that the limit doesn't exist.